# Catching AccessViolation in .NET 4. Good or bad?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, error-handling, corrupted-state-exception

There is object of type SECURITY_IDENTIFIER structure in the file. I need to get owner SID from this structure. In order to do this I call `GetSecurityDescriptorOwner` WinAPI function and create `System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier` (it has overload taking IntPtr as an argument)

The problem is this structure in file is broken sometimes, so the pointer I get from GetSecurityDescriptorOwner is invalid. It's not IntPtr.Zero, it's invalid, so when I create object of type `SecurityIdentifier` I get `AccessViolationException`, which is not possible to catch with .NET 4 with a simple try-catch.

I am aware of attribute which allows to catch such exceptions, so I used it for the time being, but I don't like this solution. It's not recommended to catch Corrupted State Exceptions (CSE), but I don't see any other solutions. This WinAPI function returns me invalid pointer and I see no way to check it for validness. Any ideas?

**update**

WinAPI

```
BOOL WINAPI GetSecurityDescriptorOwner(
  _In_   PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR pSecurityDescriptor,
  _Out_  PSID *pOwner,
  _Out_  LPBOOL lpbOwnerDefaulted
);
```

Extern definition

```
[DllImport("Advapi32.dll")]
static extern bool GetSecurityDescriptorOwner(
   IntPtr pSecurityDescriptor,
   out IntPtr owner,
   out bool defaulted);
```

**update**

```
private static SecurityIdentifier GetSecurityIdentifier()
{
    // Allocate managed buffer for invalid security descriptor structure (20 bytes)
    int[] b = new int[5] {1, 1, 1, 1, 1};

    // Allocate unmanaged memory for security descriptor 
    IntPtr descriptorPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(b.Length);

    // Copy invalid security descriptor structure to the unmanaged buffer
    Marshal.Copy(b, 0, descriptorPtr, b.Length);

    IntPtr ownerSid;
    bool defaulted;

    if (GetSecurityDescriptorGroup(descriptorPtr, out ownerSid, out defaulted))
    {
        // GetSecurityDescriptorGroup returns true, but `ownerSid` is `1`
        // Marshal.GetLastWin32Error returns 0 here
        return new SecurityIdentifier(ownerSid);
    }

    return null;
}
```

This code throws sometimes throws Corrupted State Exceptions from SecurityIdentifier constructor. Any solutions?

Comment: Can you give me your extern definition of that API method? Because maybe you should use some kind of SafeHandle instead of IntPtr. SafeHandle got IsInvalid.

Comment: Is this a custom file format that's *storing* a security descriptor within it? If so, why are you spending time trying to deal with this corrupted descriptor rather than fixing whatever is corrupting it in the first place?

Comment: It's not custom. It's HIVE file. I'm extracting SECURITY_IDENTIFIER from SK records. I can't fix it and I don't need to do this. I don't really knwo why is it corrupted, it just happens sometimes when dealing with huge amount of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried calling `IsValidSecurityDescriptor`?

```
[DllImport("Advapi32.dll")]
static extern bool IsValidSecurityDescriptor(IntPtr pSecurityDescriptor);


if (IsValidSecurityDescriptor(descriptorPtr) && 
    GetSecurityDescriptorOwner(descriptorPtr, out ownerSid, out defaulted))
{
     return new SecurityIdentifier(ownerSid);
}
```

Comment: Not really. I found only SeValidSecurityDescriptor, which says `callers of SeValidSecurityDescriptor cannot assume that a returned TRUE implies that the given security descriptor necessarily has valid contents`. This one looks better. Thanks. I'll try and post the feedback.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like this works. I'll add this function call for sure, but can I remove `[HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]` attribute and be sure that it will not return true for corrupted security descriptor structure and I'll not have the same issue again? As far as I see from MSDN it says that `function checks the validity of the components that are present in the security descriptor, It does not verify whether certain components are present.` I don't really get what this means.

Comment: @axe - glad it helps. I don't know enough about the internals to be able to be sure you won't get the same issue again.  You can only suck it and see...

Comment: Thanks. I think this is the right solution. I added try-catch block just in case, but based on the tests I performed `IsValidSecurityDescriptor` works. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated:**

Try this instead:

```
    [DllImport("Advapi32.dll")]
    static extern bool GetSecurityDescriptorOwner(
       [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.U4)]
       Int32[] securityDescriptor,
       [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.U1)] 
       out Byte[] owner,
       out Boolean defaulted);


    [DllImport("Advapi32.dll")]
    static extern bool IsValidSecurityDescriptor(
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.U4)] 
        Int32[] securityDescriptor);

    private static SecurityIdentifier GetSecurityIdentifier()
    {
        // Allocate managed buffer for invalid security descriptor structure (20 bytes)
        Int32[] b = new[] { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };

        Byte[] ownerSid;
        bool defaulted;

        if (IsValidSecurityDescriptor(b) &&
            GetSecurityDescriptorOwner(b, out ownerSid, out defaulted))
        {
            return new SecurityIdentifier(ownerSid, 0);
        }

        return null;
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        for (Int32 index = 0; index < 1000; index++)
        {
            SecurityIdentifier identifier = GetSecurityIdentifier();
            String text = identifier == null ? "(none)" : identifier.Value;
            Console.WriteLine(text);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll test it tomorrow morning and post the feedback.

Comment: Here is what I get with SafeHandle `Cannot marshal 'parameter #2': Ref and out SafeHandle parameters cannot be abstract.`

Comment: I don't care about error type. Those files are most probably broken, I just need to take the information that is possible to take. In case of error I just need to write log entry and ignore it. The problem is GetSecurityDescriptorOwner returns true sometimes, but gives invalid pointer. I was able to reproduce this locally, see the updated example.

Comment: You can probably use SafeFileHandle instead of SafeHandle, I didn't realized it was out parameter. Unless the IsValidSecurityDescriptor solution doesn't work of course. :)

Comment: I was able to call function with SafeFileHandle, however it doesn't help much. It still says that the handle is valid, but crashes when I use the pointer. Im currently running application with test data, looks like IsValidSecurityDescriptor helps, not finished yet, but still no crash.

Comment: OK, it probably only checks superficial pointer validity. Can't you use something like LookupAccountSid afterwards to find out whether it will look something up or not? Provided, that the Microsoft would know how to handle the owner pointer in any state. This issue is really peculiar.

Comment: Or alternatively you can try to marshal the SID to Byte[]: [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] out Byte[] owner. Then use SecurityIdentifier(Byte[], 0) constructor instead.

Comment: I've also noticed that you got: out IntPtr owner, out bool owner.. two owner variables, I hope it is only a typo in the question.

Comment: With regards to the owner variable - yes, that's just a typo. Fixed :)

Comment: [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] out Byte[] doesn't help much, because in this case the problem still remains, but now the SCE is thrown from GetSecurityDescriptorOwner function.

Comment: Well, if the LookupAccountSid (http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32.lookupaccountsid) won't fly (I'd just use lpSystemName = null, lpName = null, referencedDomainName = null, ref cchName = 0, ref cchReferenceDomainName = 0). I would probably go with CSE. It is not forbidden, it's just the last measure. Unless somebody gives you some other hint.

Comment: OK, I've finally got some time to look on it in a real life. I've come up with this variant. It skips the pointers entirely.

Comment: Yes. That's what I did now. It works (couldn't find any crashes during tests). I also added try-catch and enabled SCE handling for the function GetSecurityIdentifier just in case. If IsValidSecurityDescriptor works AccessViolationException will never be thrown and that's good. In case if it is thrown though, it will get caught by the catch block and ignored.

Comment: Did you tried that updated solution? It does away with exception all together as it doesn't use IntPtr. Because IsValidSecurityDescriptor (while using the IntPtrs) still caused some exceptions when I tried it.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice you changed signature. I tried something similar previously and the function GetSecurityDescriptorOwner was throwing SCE, but I'll try this one as well and let you know.

Comment: Well. It works with IsValidSecurityDescriptor, but I guess it works because of IsValidSecurityDescriptor check, because as soon as I remove this check it throws SCE again, so I don't see any difference.

Comment: OK, if it works for you. It was throwing SCEs when I used only IsValidSecurityDescriptor. Usually it crashed within 1000 attempts, thus the for loop. But more important is, that it works for you. See you around. :)